# How can I delimit a variable to be within a range of numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

```
read primeranota  
if test $primeranota ={1..10} \
    -o  $primeranota!={A..Z} \
    -o  $primeranota !={a..z}  ; then
    echo "Nota introducida con exito."
    pausa
else
    until "$primeranota" -ge 0 -a "$primeranota" -le 10; do
        echo -n "Escribe una nota del [0-10]: "
        read primeranota
    done
```

I also wanted to limit the input to just numbers, but I dunno how can I limit that.

I've been stuck with this for days... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern:

```
#!/bin/bash
unset input
shopt -s extglob # For bash < 4.1.
until [[ $input == @(0|[1-9]*([0-9])) && $input -le 10 ]]; do
    read -r input
done
```

- `@` means one of the alternatives must be present, i.e. either 0, or a positive number
- positive number starts with a non-zero `[1-9]`, followed by any digit (or none) `*([0-9])`.

Comment: But how can i make it if the users fails again to put a number between 0-10 and puts a letter or something

Comment: @nabmaster: Updated.

Comment: It gives me this error `shell.sh: 29: shell.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "do")`

Comment: @nabmaster: What's your bash version?

Comment: Prior to `bash` 4.1, you need to use `shopt -s extglob` to use `@(...)` inside `[[...]]`.

Comment: @choroba bash 4.3.42

Comment: @nabmaster: It should work. Do you run the script in bash?

Comment: @choroba it works but now when i type a thing that its not between those limits it got me this error inside the program but it still works, so now i just want to know how can I keep out this error. `shell.sh: line 28: shop: command not found`

Comment: @choroba And can I do this with sh?

Comment: @nabmaster: Oh, my typo, should've been `shopt`. Fixed. No easy way in `sh`.

Comment: @chorba : +1 for for working answer and tech support, but "no easy way in sh"? what about `case "${input}" in [0-9]|[0-9][0-9]) ....` ? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: True. I meant "comparably easy" :-)

Answer (score 1):

POSIX shell, (no **bash**isms).  When the *size* of the number doesn't matter, (i.e. the number is less than 19 digits or so), use the "**-eq**" test operator, which fails if a string is not an integer.  Here's a "**readbetween**" script to use that:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: readbetween n1 n2
# inputs one line from standard input between (and including) n1 and n2
unset s n
IsNumber()  # usage: IsNumber string
{           #  returns: flag
        [ $1 -eq $1 ] 2> /dev/null
}

read -p "Number between $1 and $2?  " n
if IsNumber "$n" ; then
    if [ $n -gt $2 ] ; then
        s=big
    elif [ $n -lt $1 ] ; then
        s=small
    else
        echo $n
        exit 0
    fi
else
    s=stringy
fi
echo "too $s: $n" > /dev/stderr
exit 1
```

Test run, invoke with:

until x=`./readbetween 0 10` ; do : ; done ; echo $x

...and suppose the user makes mistakes:

> Number between 0 and 10?  33
>   too big: 33
>   Number between 0 and 10?  abc
>   too stringy: abc
>   Number between 0 and 10?  5.5
>   too stringy: 5.5
>   Number between 0 and 10?  -1
>   too small: -1
>   Number between 0 and 10?  4
>   4

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[[ ... ]]` in bash:

```
read -r input
if [[ "$input" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo '$input contains 0-9, a-z and A-Z only'
fi
```

This allows `0-9`, `a-z` and `A-Z` one more more times.

Comment: I don't know if I was clear in the explanation but what i wanted to do is to restric the var to be a number between 0-10 and if a letter is entered just make another bucle that tells u that u need to enter a number.

Answer (score 0):

To allow just numbers for `$primeranota` :

```
read primeranota
[[ $mavar =~ [0-9]*[0-9] ]] && echo numbers
```

To allow numbers in range 1 to 10 :

```
shopt -s extglob # you may have to set extglob to 'on'
until [[ $primeranota == @(0|[1-9]|10) ]]; do
    echo -n "Escribe una nota del [0-10]:"
    read primeranota
done
```